# System crash after oracle installation with yum

Tags: linux, oracle11g, yum

recently i tried to install oracle on my linux with apt (I never used yum before) using fast manual:

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-admin/ginnydbinstallonlinux-488779.html
```

And after command:

```
sudo yum install oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall
```

I got error: 
    Failed: ca-certificates.noarch 0:2010.63-3.el6_1.5 chkconfig.x86_64 0:1.3.49.3-2.el6 file-libs.x86_64 0:5.04-15.el6 filesystem.x86_64 0:2.4.30-3.el6
initscripts.x86_64 0:9.03.38-1.0.1.el6_4.2

```
Complete!
```

And something gone wrong because command like: ps, top are crashing

```
login@Ass-K55VJ:/etc/yum/repos.d$ ps -e
ps: relocation error: ps: symbol procps_number_version, version _3_2_5 not defined in        file libproc-3.2.8.so with link time reference

login@Ass-K55VJ:/etc/yum/repos.d$ top 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
then I tryied to uninstall oracle and dependencies but after command:

sudo yum remove oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall

There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

No module named yum

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
```

2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 10 2013, 06:42:56) [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)]

```
If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to the yum faq at:     http://wiki.linux.duke.edu/YumFaq
```

So it seems like yum install in my system new libraries but didn't link it correctly? I dont know what do in this moment because it seems like armagedon on my ubuntu...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this mean you're on ubuntu and tried to install rpm packages using yum? The manual you used is for *Oracle Linux 6*, why would you try that on ubuntu?

`rpm` packages are not compatible with debian based systems like ubuntu, which use `deb` packages. So you've probably screwed your system big time, overwriting important system libraries with incompatible ones.

If apt-get is still working, then you can try to reinstall (`apt-get --reinstall install`) the equivalent libraries to the ones mentioned in the install manual you linked to - naming isn't always the same for rpm and deb packages. `dpkg -l` should help you see which the correct installed libraries are. I'd start with the C libraries (libc) etc.

But if apt-get is screwed also, then you'd need to download the packages manually from an ubuntu mirror and install them using `dpkg`, but I think a reinstall (or restore from backup if you have one) would be the best option.

Comment: "The manual you used is for Oracle Linux 6, why would you try that on ubuntu?" -I'm new user that unfortunately learn from his mistakes. But for luck apt is still working so I will try reinstall libraries. Thank You!